# How to prevent dns recursive queries on a Windows 2008 R2 server?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2

I have been tasked in managing a server, but I did not receive any training concerning DNS configuration. I come from the programming world, so I'm aware of certain concept, but not everything.

We are having trouble with some ISP when we try to send some email, so IK'm trying to fix any DNS related error that could make our email bounce.

I am using http://www.intodns.com/groupetoundra.com to check any problem left on the DNS setup.

I am currently trying to resolve the "recursive queries" problem that say:

> Recursive Queries
>
> I could use the nameservers listed below to performe recursive queries. It may be that I am wrong but the chances of that are low. You should not have nameservers that allow recursive queries as this will allow almost anyone to use your nameservers and can cause problems. Problem record(s) are:
>
> 70.38.39.242
>
> 70.38.39.241

I am using Simple DNS Plus to configure the DNS.

What can I do to remove the recursive queries problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The SimpleDNS Plus on-line documentation tells you the answer.](http://simpledns.com/help/v52/wd_opt_dnsrecur.htm)  This really isn't anything to do with mail delivery, and not something that's going to fix your mail problems, but [it's best practice not to supply public proxy DNS service](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/proxy-server-ip-addresses.html) and so a good idea to reconfigure your DNS server anyway.

Comment: You are wrong, does not work.